# Pinescript self incremental variable in IF ELSE

Tags: pine-script

i need some help in figuring this function out, which is quite common in other language.

I have a var called multiplier that if my previous trades is a winning trade, i want the multiplier to *2

basically an anti martingale bet calls.

```
longCondition = (some condition)

wintrades = valuewhen(longCondition[1], strategy.wintrades, 0)
losstrades = valuewhen(longCondition[1], strategy.losstrades, 0)

multiplier = 1
if(wintrades+losstrades == 0 or losstrades[0] > losstrades[1])
    multiplier := 1
else
    multiplier := multiplier*2

lotsize = bet*multiplier
```

this is as far as i could crack my head, since the script always read at first, i woudn't be able to get multiplier to pass *2.

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define `multiplier` as a `var`.
That way, the value is retained throughout the script.

```
longCondition = (some condition)

wintrades = valuewhen(longCondition[1], strategy.wintrades, 0)
losstrades = valuewhen(longCondition[1], strategy.losstrades, 0)

var multiplier = 1

if(wintrades+losstrades == 0 or losstrades[0] > losstrades[1])
    multiplier := 1
else
    multiplier := multiplier*2

lotsize = bet*multiplier
```

The way you wrote it, resets `multiplier` to `1` at every bar.